# Python multiprocessing Queue vs Pipe vs SharedMemory

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I want to run two Python processes in parallel, with each being able to send data to and receive data from the other at any time. [Python's multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) seems to have multiple solutions to this, such as Queue, Pipe, and SharedMemory. What are the pros and cons of using each of these, and which one would be best for accomplishing this specific goal?

Answer (score 4):

It comes down to **what** you want to share, **who** you want to share it with, how **often** you want to share it, what your latency requirements are, and your skill-set, your maintainability needs and your preferences. Then there are the usual tradeoffs to be made between performance, legibility, upgradeability and so on.

If you are sharing native Python objects, they will generally be most simply shared via a *"multiprocessing queue"* because they will be packaged up before transmission and unpackaged on receipt.

If you are sharing large arrays, such as images, you will likely find that *"multiprocessing shared memory"* has least overhead because there is no pickling involved. However, if you want to share such arrays with other machines across a network, shared memory will not work, so you may need to resort to **Redis** or some other technology. Generally, *"multiprocessing shared memory"* takes more setting up, and requires you to do more to synchronise access, but is more performant for larger data-sets.

If you are sharing between Python and C/C++ or another language, you may elect to use protocol buffers and pipes, or again **Redis**.

As I said, there are many tradeoffs and opinions - far more than I have addressed here. The first thing though is to determine your needs in terms of bandwidth, latency, flexibility and then think about the most appropriate technology.